# TailWindCss Responsive design not working

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

```
const Cards = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                <div className="flex bg-gray-300 w-3/12 md:flex-col lg:flex-row justify-around rounded-lg shadow-lg m-4 min-w-[295px]">
                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between items-center m-7">
                        <img
                            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562774053-701939374585?q=80&w=1000&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8Y29sbGVnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D"
                            className="h-32 rounded-lg"
                        />
                        <button className="bg-blue-300 rounded-lg m-2 p-3 font-semibold w-20">
                            Enroll
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="font-semibold m-7 ">
                        <p className="mb-2">College Name</p>
                        <p className="mb-2">Location</p>
                        <p className="mb-2">Number</p>
                        <p className="mb-2">Description</p>
                        <p className="mb-2">Email</p>
                        <p className="mb-2">Courses</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Cards;
```

Used Vite js for this , in xl and larger screens it should be flex-col and in smaller screen sm,md,lg it should be in flex-row !

For Larger xl and more : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOhZH.png)
In Smaller Screens sm,md,lg it should be : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUuYw.png)

It should be rendered like in the image based on the conditions which is provided.

Comment: update : Any responsive class are not working , i have view port in index.html in the vite !